# How to install windows and replace failed hard disk on a netbook running linux?

Tags: windows-7, linux, hard-drive, netbook, bootable-media

I have an Acer aspire one d270 netbook(No CD drive). My uncle installed Linux on it. He's no more. I dont know anything about linux. And now the hard disk (Seagate ST320LT012) also failed. Im gonna purchase Western Digital WD5000LPVX Hard disk. Please somebody tell me how to install the hard disk and windows on it.

Comment: Unless you have the Windows 7 product key, you will have to shell out another ~$100 for Windows. Also, try [Google](http://www.google.com) for how to install Windows and how to replace hard drives...

Comment: If the machine was purchased from Acer then it likely came with Windows.  If it came with Windows there will be a WOA sticker which will contain the license key for the version of Windows it came with.  If there is no sticker then you will have to purchase Windows yourself.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is not as difficult as you might think.

**Replacing the hard disk**

This is a excellent video on YouTube, [Acer One Aspire D270 SSD and Ram Upgrade](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nJYcHrwE1ok). Actually there are a number of videos out there, on YouTube.

Running through the steps quickly:

1. Turn the laptop over.
2. Remove the battery.
3. Remove the keyboard (this could be tricky, and be gentle - watch the video).
4. Remove the ribbon cable - gently.
5. Remove all of the screws labelled "door".
6. Apply pressure to the "door release" tab.
7. Remove the underside door.
8. Remove the hard disk (pry it out with a screwdriver).
9. Disconnect the SATA cable.
10. Connect the SATA cable to the new drive.
11. Insert the new drive.

Reverse the process to close the laptop back up.

**Installing Windows**

You have two, or three, options:

1. Obtain a "cheap" Repair/Reinstall disk, maybe from eBay? (this is the cheapest and easiest solution)
2. Purchase a licensed (new) version of Windows7
3. Bootable USB stick containing a Windows install image (most labour intensive option - and so I will not go into details)

As other contributors have stated, your laptop will have a Windows COA sticker on the underside with a license key. You can use that, so there is no need to purchase a "new" copy of windows, so you can discount option 2.

As your machine has no built-in CD drive, options one and two will require you to get hold of an external USB DVD drive. Assuming you go with option one:

1. Connect the DVD drive
2. Insert the Reinstall disk, and boot from it
3. Run through the install process
4. When you are asked for a license key, just type in the one on the
   underside of the laptop (it would be best to write it down on some
   paper before you connect the the DVD drive).

Answer (score 0):

Replacing hard drive in Aspire One series is a bit complicated, so you may want professionals to handle it for you. If you want to do it yourself, [this service manual](http://tim.id.au/laptops/acer/aspire%20one.pdf) will be handy. Disassembly instructions start on page 44.

Make sure battery is removed. HDD case is located under the keyboard. Removing LCD panel isn't necessary. Replace HDD and reassemble your netbook carefully.

As @Ramhound said in his comment, it's very likely that you already have a Windows 7 license - look for a sticker on the bottom of the computer. If you don't have one, you'll have to purchase Windows 7.

Finally, you'll need another PC, a 4 GB (or bigger) flash drive and Windows 7 DVD or [ISO image](https://superuser.com/q/78761/194694). Make sure to download the right image, as the serial number from your license sticker will work only for specific edition of Windows. If you have a DVD that you have purchased with license, it will suffice.

Use the [Windows USB/DVD Download Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/windows-usb-dvd-download-tool) to create a bootable flash drive. It will ask you to insert the DVD or select ISO image. When the process completes, connect this flash drive to netbook's USB port and boot from it. You'll probably have to press <kbd>F12</kbd> on the initial Acer logo screen, then select flash drive.

The process of installing Windows 7 after booting from flash drive is identical as if you'd boot from DVD. It's pretty simple and well documented, just use Google if you encounter any problems.